# what to return in postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have function to reduce stock_qty of product by the qty in the order

```
CREATE or REPLACE function update_stock_quantity()
returns TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN

UPDATE products set quantity_stock = products.quantity_stock - order_details.quantity_stock 
FROM products INNER JOIN order_details on products.id = order_details.product_id;
END; 
$$
language plpgsql
```

with a trigger function on order_detail table

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_stock_qty AFTER
INSERT
    ON order_details FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_stock_quantity();
```

and I get this error
error: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN

how to use return in the function

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **NOT** repeat the target table of an UPDATE in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) "*A trigger function must return either NULL or a record/row value having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.*"

Answer (score 0):

You must use RETURN, adding the code line "RETURN NEW;":

```
CREATE or REPLACE function update_stock_quantity()
returns TRIGGER AS
$$
BEGIN

UPDATE products set quantity_stock = products.quantity_stock - order_details.quantity_stock 
FROM products INNER JOIN order_details on products.id = order_details.product_id;
RETURN NEW;
END; 
$$
language plpgsql
```